# 2d vector subscripts going out of range even when the subscripts are in range

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

So I am trying to write a simple code that will take in 2 strings from the users. It then takes the length of the strings using length() and creates a matrix (2d vector) of ints based on the lengths. I then need to set the values of the last row and last column to have values of powers of 2. 
If the entered strings are "happy" & "sad" the resulting matrix should be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 6
0 0 0 0 0 4
0 0 0 0 0 2 
10 8 6 4 2 0
```

I am generating the matrix like this:

```
    vector<vector<int>> opt;
    unsigned int x, y;
    x = (sequenceOne.length()) + 1;
    y = (sequenceTwo.length()) + 1;

    unsigned int p,q;

    opt.resize(y, vector<int>(x, 0)); // resizes the matrix
```

When I try to change values in the matrix with:

```
    opt[2][2] = 5;
```

It works fine, but when I go to access the last row last column like this:

```
    opt[x][y]
```

It tells me "Expression: vector subscript out of range"
I think it has something to do with the getting the length of the strings to use as the values, but I can't for the life of me figure out why that would cause an issue.
I have tried making the subscripts different variables, different orders, and stuff like opt[x-1][y-1] but the error still occurs.

I'm not sure if it matters but I am using MS VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are 0 indexed. `x` and `y` are the size of the arrays.  You can't use the size value as an index value.

For instance:
[image]

`a` is of size 5. `"a"` is at index 0, `"e"` is at index 4. `"e"` is the 5th element in the list. When you try to use the size of 5 as the index, well there is no element at index 5, as you can see.  The last element would be accessed `a[size - 1]`.  Though remember, size of 0 results in an index of -1, which is an invalid index.

Comment: Thank you very much. Not sure how I overlooked that. This solved the problem.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, it can be easy to overlook these things. Now hopefully it'll stick. :) Sometimes takes a good bite in the butt for people to remember things. ;p

Answer (score 0):

C++ arrays work like this:

```
vector<int> v = {2, 4, 6, 8}
//index:         0  1  2  3
```

Therefore, the last element in the array would actually be `opt[x - 1][y - 1]`.